# Save raw image data in a RAW format using Java?

Tags: java, image, image-processing, photo

I have raw pixel data from an image sensor. The pixel data is totally unprocessed, and is still in a Bayer mosaic (BGGR), which is common with many digital cameras. Rather than process it myself, probably badly, I would like to output the data in an unprocessed form that could be read by a standard graphics package. I was thinking about something like Digital Negative (DNG), TIFF or similar, but there may be something simpler. Any associated meta-data does not need to contain anything complicated (I don't have the time or location that the image was taken, for example), but I do have a simple greyscale bitmap thumbnail, if relevant).

Is there a Java library that will allow me to write any kind of raw image format that could be read by an off-the-shelf graphics processing tool, such as dcraw, which could then be used to de-mosaic the image?

Comment: The javax.imageio provides some classes to read and write in various common formats such as JPG and PNG (TIFF is not included, but there are readers for it online). It requires you to convert your RAW format to a BufferedImage though, before it can be written to PNG or JPG.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately I don't have an image, I have only raw detector pixel data. To convert to an image I would have to demosaic the data which involves interpolation and potentially other processing. I would rather not do this myself (badly) and leave it for an existing tool which can do a better job. Existing tools expect a RAW format, which contain exactly this data but I don't know how to write one.

Comment: @PMendham The easiest is probably prepend your Bayer CFA data with a TIFF header that conforms to DNG (DNG is a TIFF subtype). I know DNG supports uncompressed CFA data. See the [DNG spec](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/dng_spec_1.4.0.0.pdf). I have [Java code that *reads* DNG](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/camera-raw/imageio/imageio-dng/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/imageio/plugins/dng/DNGImageReader.java) (work in progress, supports only uncompressed CFA, and does a poor job of de-mosaicing/processing the RGB data) you could look at.

Comment: @haraldK Thanks for your reply, and for your example code. I think this is what I'll try and do. I'm quite new to this though, so I have quite a lot to learn! (That's why I cheekily hoped that someone else had already solved this problem ;) )